# Adding support for multi-select dropdown for an attribute to an existing entity

Tags: mysql

I have an existing schema `student` as follows:

```
  CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `grade` varchar(255) NOT NULL
  );
```

Now, for a given student, I would like to add multi-select support for new column `house` which is of type enumeration as follows:

```
public enum House {
  House1("house1"),
  House2("house2"),
  House3("house3"),
  House4("house4"),
  House5("house5"),
  House6("house6"),
  House7("house7");

  private final String value;

  House(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

As per the requirement, followings need to be supported:

1. a `student` may belong to one or more than one `house`,
2. anytime a `student` leaves one or more of the existing `house`(s) and/or attached to a one or more new `house`(s).

To implement this, two approaches came to my mind:

**Approach 1**:

Adding one column of larger length, say `varchar(1024)`, where we can put concatenation of all `house`s given `student` belongs to.

**Approach 2**:
Adding two more schemas as follows:

1. Schema for `house`:

```
CREATE TABLE `house` (
  `name` varchar(250)  NOT NULL
 );
```

2. Schema for `student_house_association`:

```
CREATE TABLE `student_house_association` (
   `student_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
   `house` varchar(250)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_student` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `student` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_house` FOREIGN KEY (`house`) REFERENCES `house` (`name`)
);
```

I am really confused about which approach should I take among these two.

Comment: _put concatenation of all houses given student belongs to_ That is a terrible idea. See database normalisation. So go for option 2

Comment: Hi, @RiggsFolly thanks for your response. If possible, could you please briefly explain why do you think option 2 is better than option 1?

Comment: That is actually fairly simple. Imaging the query you would have to write to select all the students that belong to one specific House